# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject special characters Unterminated string. Expected delimiter:

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

For some reason, when I have a special character in my knockout model and convert it to a json object, the string ends where the special character is supposed to be and I get an error when deserializing it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/Forms/Convert",
    type: "post",
        //contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "text",
        data: "modelData=" + ko.toJSON(theModel),
        success: function (data) {

            // window.open("/Admin/Forms/DisplayClient");
            var win = getFullWindow('/Admin/Forms/DisplayClient');
            win.open();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
```

When I get to this method:

```
public void Convert(string modelData)
{
    Form form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(modelData);
}
```

I get an error:

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'Name', line 1, position 178.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a JSON string contains special characters like double quotes `"`, backslashes `\` or slashes `/`, they need to be escaped with backslashes `\`. There is no JSON parser that will be able to deal with a JSON string that isn't properly formatted in the first place.

So you need to make sure that your `theModel` is formatted appropriately and according to [JSON.org](http://JSON.org) standards.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I found an answer to my own question:

    escape(ko.toJSON(theModel))




All I need is the escape function and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same error a few times. I have updated my web.config with greater max lengths to ensure no truncating.

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151" />

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="2097151" maxUrl="2097151" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component.

This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

This has now been added to my ajax requests:

```
$.ajax("URL", {
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: { a: encodeURIComponent(jsonData), b: userID }
})
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I have found the problem was because of the special character @. 
The encodeURIComponent() function did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question: escape(ko.toJSON(theModel)) All I need is the escape function and it works great.

Comment: ??, C# has no idea what "escape" is

Comment: this is a javascript function which has been deprecated (v1.5) see my answer for current answer. c# version of this would be Uri.UnescapeDataString()

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and I solved it by using JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` Function to encode the JSON data.

```
encodeURIComponent(data);
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.