# Why is my ajax post being truncated?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, iis, knockout.js

I have just updated my mvc service to include greater error and logging. I have now got this exact error several times. But cannot replicate.

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'Breadcrumbs[18].Params', line 1, position 59740. at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote) at
```

The Path is different each time, depending on what the user is sending to the server.

My ajax requests generally look like this:

```
$.ajax(myURL("SendBreadcrumbs"), {
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { telemetry: telemetry.JSONify(), userID: currentUser, isMyVI: isMyVI }
        })
```

In these cases, userID and isMyVI (boolean) didnt exist and the telemetry string is truncated.

JSONify method is as follows:

```
self.JSONify = function () {
    var data = ko.mapping.toJSON(self, TelemetryMapping);
    return data;
}
```

This is knockoutJSs serializer.

Server Side:

```
public void SendBreadcrumbs(string telemetry, string userID = null, bool isMyVI = true)
{
    MyServiceAudit audit;
    Guid UserID;
    if (Guid.TryParse(userID, out UserID))
        audit = InsertAudit(UserID);
    else
        audit = InsertAudit(null);
    try
    {
        Models.Telemetry data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Telemetry>(telemetry);
        Controllers.Telemetry.UpdateTelemetry(data, isMyVI);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MyServiceAuditDB.FailAudit(audit.ID, ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

I am completely stumped, i have tried updating the web.config on the server with larger maxvalues etc, to see its truncating on that side.

The only other difference i have in my ajax is a global timeout of 3mins.

Is this as simple as special characters not being handled on client side, or server side limitations, or is the data so large it gets chunked and server side doesn't know to wait for the next chunk?

Comment: How big **is** the data?

Comment: Its as long as a piece of string tbh. I record the http params before deserialising etc (HttpContext.Request.Params.ToString()). So one of the failed requests this is 117,454 characters long?

Comment: Also just checked i have params of this size 3,119,214. Which did not fail? So can I rule out truncation due to size?

Comment: Just an FYI on your exception handling. If you do `ex.ToSring()` you will get the message, stacktrace and also all of the inner exceptions. Depending on the exception, the inner exceptions are actually what you want to help resolve issues.

Comment: Thanks, Ill make a note for that.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you're trying to send? Does it have a lot of special characters?

Comment: I can't post a sample of the data (data protection) but it will contain free hand data entered by the user with no restrictions and javascript objects that would already be stringified but these stay as strings. so clients names easily could include & ' etc also.

Comment: Can you run a trace on the requests until one fails? Then you might be able to see the problem from the traced request, or at least have a repro..

Comment: Try using something like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the data as it's being sent so you know for sure whether it's getting truncated before it gets to the server or after.

Comment: I Definitly think it is you JSON convertion that have trouble. Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565404/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-special-characters-unterminated-string-expected-d/21584973
From your line:
Models.Telemetry data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Telemetry>(telemetry);
The data send will have trouble since not all chars are escaped in your Json

Comment: For me it is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565404/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-special-characters-unterminated-string-expected-d
have a look at System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode, hope it helps

Comment: could you show `TelemetryMapping`, do you get the bindings from an observable? with `text` or `html` binding?

Comment: Your problem is about *Newtonsoft.Json*. So what about `JSONify()` or `JSON.stringify()` for the currentUser and isMyVI

Comment: Can you also post the `Telemetry` model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from a few comments, answers and finally got live failed data, I was able to resolve this.

It turned out that not only did the user use special characters, but also some of the static data sent down included this (GIGO - couldn't believe the state of some of our data).

**Client Side Solution:**

*The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component.
This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #*

```
$.ajax(myURL("SendBreadcrumbs"), {
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { telemetry: encodeURIComponent(telemetry.JSONify()), userID: currentUser, isMyVI: isMyVI }
    })
```

**Server Side Solution:**

*Converts a string to its unescaped representation. Uri.UnescapeDataString()*

```
public void SendBreadcrumbs(string telemetry, string userID = null, bool isMyVI = true)
{
    MyServiceAudit audit;
    Guid UserID;
    if (Guid.TryParse(userID, out UserID))
        audit = InsertAudit(UserID);
    else
        audit = InsertAudit(null);
    try
    {
        Models.Telemetry data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Telemetry>(Uri.UnescapeDataString(telemetry));
        Controllers.Telemetry.UpdateTelemetry(data, isMyVI);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MyServiceAuditDB.FailAudit(audit.ID, ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

**Web Application Configuration:**

I had a user getting a 500 error, due to trying to send 20 emails. I updated the config to include maximum request length (in kilobytes, example is 1GB) and max content length (in bytes, example is 1GB). Emails came through no issue. Couldn't believe it!

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"  />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using the fiddler for getting the rough idea of what data is actually sent. It is surely the problem from de-serialization and your code looks completely fine. Size of the data should not be an issue here, get some raw view of data and you should be fine.

Also see if the JSONify() return the data formatted correctly without escaping the character sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Try using encodeURIComponent for the content entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which version of jQuery you're using, but when we assume a stable release we can be sure that the necessary encoding and escaping in the downline of `$.ajax()` is flawless.

If request length was the cause, we would see a http error on client side and no call of the server-side function ("max request length exceeded"). This is supported by your observation that requests with longer strings can succeed while shorter ones can fail.

I'd suggest two actions:

1) To reduce fragmentation, layering and possible misleading diagnoses, do not JSONify just the telemetry. Construct your object out of telemetry, userID and isMyVi, then JSONify *that* as a whole (that means, include the meta data in the `TelemetryMapping` description if possible)

2) Inspect the value of `telemetry.JSONify()` at runtime client-side. If you find that the truncation is caused by this, focus on knockoutJS version and integrity, or replace. As @Destrif points out in their comment, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565447/1132334 suggests that it may not be part of knockoutJS's tasks to escape double quotes, backslashes and slashes -

which may be as simple as wrapping the call in another `escape()`:

```
self.JSONify = function () {
    var data = escape(ko.mapping.toJSON(self, TelemetryMapping));
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead.