# JQuery ajax GET request calls success with truncated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to retrieve a large amount of data from my server via a JQuery ajax GET request. The returned data is truncated (see image below). When I make the same exact request via my web browser by navigating directly to the URL, I get the full response, which is a JSON object (see image below).

I initially set the dataType option in my ajax call to "json", but I switched it to "text" because the ajax error function was being triggered (couldn't parse truncated json). Now it calls the success function, despite the fact that it hasn't finished receiving the data.

A couple more points worth noting: Occasionally it will work and load all of the data, but still fails most of the time. I'm using a Node.js/Express server and `res.json()` to send the response object.

Code:

```js
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: myURL,
    method: "GET",
    success: (data) => { resolve(data); },
    error: (err) => { reject(err); },
    timeout: 1000000
})
```

[image: JQuery ajax call doesn't wait to receive entire response, resulting in truncated data.]

Comment: It sounds like your timeout is being hit due to the request taking far too long. The short fix is to increase the timeout. The better fix is to re-engineer your site so that you don't need to download this ridiculous amount of data. Use paging/filtering/searching on the server side to only show the user relevant data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't think it's the timeout, because it only has to wait for ~5 seconds for the response, and I set the timeout to 100 seconds. I tried increasing in to 1,000 seconds in case the "Receiving" time is part of the timeout, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Even setting timeout to 0, which according to the jQuery docs makes it so there is no timeout, doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `fetch()` just for testing purposes? Can you provide a sample data sent by your server, or replicate the data using dummy values, so we can hopefully reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried loading the page in Chrome and it seems to be working reliably. Somehow it doesn't seem to be truncating the data. Not the best workaround, but could be a useful clue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some times ago.

The problem was originated by a wrong `Content-Length` set by the API server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't actually fix the issue for me, but it helped me to rule out some things and get a better understanding of the issue. So far I've only been able to get it to work by using Chrome instead of Firefox, so I'm not sure if there is some default browser behavior related to receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

try to set at your API server, add php function `set_time_limit($second);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically because of insufficient encoding of the data you must try `encodeURIComponent()`,by this function each instance of certain characters will be replaced by  one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

Most of the errors(such as  truncated data) are resolved by this encoding because as per the documentation the `$.ajax` function will only process approximately 50 characters of the return string, ignoring the rest.

And you can even test this by decreasing the number of characters in your returned data.

**To make it short you can try for**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: myURL,
    method: "GET",
    success: (data) => { resolve(encodeURIComponent(data)); },
    error: (err) => { reject(err); },
    timeout: 10000
})
```

**Here are some resources by which you can relate your problem**

[Jquery Fixes](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1740)

[Client Side Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898747/why-is-my-ajax-post-being-truncated)

[JavaScript AJAX variables truncation issue FIX](https://www.vikaskbh.com/javascript-ajax-variables-truncation-issue-fix/)