# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws an Error after using the result from JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net

When I use Newtonsoft.Json in C#, I find a problem like this

```
var dataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();

dataDict["$id"] = new List<double>() { 0.1, 0.9 };

var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataDict);

var back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<double>>>(jsonStr);
```

Then it throws error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected token when
> deserializing object: Float. Path '$id[0]', line 1, position 11.'

If I remove the charater "$", it works.

I acknowledge "$" is a speical token, my question: if you can SerializeObject, why you can not DeserializeObject?

Any work around here? Any advice is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject special characters Unterminated string. Expected delimiter:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565404/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-special-characters-unterminated-string-expected-d)

Comment: $id is a special value to Newtonsoft, it's for object reference serialization. It will look for another object with the id "{ 0.1, 0.9 }" and doesn't like that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Json.NET to ignore metadata properties (properties prefaced by '$') by passing `JsonSerializerSettings` to your deserialize operation.

```
var back = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<double>>>(
    jsonStr,
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore 
    });
```

This correctly deserializes into your target dictionary structure:

[image]